# Pass quote character to shell via Latex

Tags: shell, awk, latex

I need to pass quote (") characters to a shell via Latex for using the printf-command:

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\calcCorrelation}[1]{{\input{|"awk '
{
...
}
END{...
printf("\@percentchar.2f",r); 
}
' #1; 
"}
}}
\makeatother
```

I get an syntax-failure, because the quotes around \@percentchar.2f are not passed. How can I fix this? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Are you absolutely sure you need to go down from latex into your shell to run an awk command? Latex provides a great source of "calc" operations. You would just have to search a little bit for it.

Comment: Yes, i'm sure about this. The AWK-Shell-Script works with experimental data, which is stored in a csv-File (path is passed via argument #1). I think that Latex is not able to do these calculations and it's not built for that.

Comment: If your `awk` script is not dynamic, write it to a file and just call with `awk -f scriptname`.

Comment: " is not listed as special character, but the " terminates the string. So maybe this could work: `printf("'"'"\@percentchar.2f"'"'",r); `

Answer (score 0):

Try using a variable -- somewhat like the following:

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\calcCorrelation}[1]{{\input{|"awk -v pc="\@percentchar.2f" '
{
        ...
}
END {
        ...
        printf(pc,r); 
}
' #1; 
"}
}}
\makeatother
```

Caveat: I do not know if you need/want the quotes around *\@percentchar.2f* in this case?